# Hover effect isn't working on the pseudo element

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Trying to add hover effect on the pseudo element (on the bottom arrow as well the whole border around) but it doesn't effects and looks like the image below with white arrow and black square, what I am doing wrong here that its not working even I see most of the stacks overflow answer are the same as my one.

Also when I hover on the black border then both border around and the green circle should change it color at the same time, but it seems like it does not happens ( the hovering) at the same time.
Any help will be much appreciated!

[image]

```css
.outer-circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.inner-circle {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: #3ac371;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 21px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
}

.outer-circle::before {
  content: "";
  top: 72px;
  left: 24px;
  border-width: 16px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.outer-circle:hover {
  background: black;
}

.outer-circle:hover:before {
  background-color: black;
}

.dl-inner-circle:hover {
  background: #9f1853;
}
```

```html
<!-- template -->
<div>
  <div class="markar-container">
    <button>
        <h1>Pin</h1>
        <div class="outer-circle">
          <div class="inner-circle" @click="onClick">
            <div class="text">AA</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /template -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Target the `border-right-color` instead of the `background-color`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() {}
  }
})
```

```css
.outer-circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.inner-circle {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background: #3ac371;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 21px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
}

.outer-circle::before {
  content: "";
  top: 72px;
  left: 24px;
  border-width: 16px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  filter: drop-shadow(-8px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3));
}

.outer-circle:hover {
  background: black;
}

.outer-circle:hover:before {
  border-right-color: black;
}

.dl-inner-circle:hover {
  background: #9f1853;
}


/* .dl-outer-circle:hover:after {
  background: black;
  border-width: 2px;
} */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div>
    <div class="markar-container">
      <button>
        <h1>Pin</h1>
        <div class="outer-circle">
          <div class="inner-circle" @click="onClick">
            <div class="text">AA</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @James, border-right-color did work perfectly. I added also box-shadow on before :  .outer-circle::before { box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }
but the shadow doesnot cover the arrow instead it's looking very odd. How can I fix this issue so the shadow shows around the arrow ( before) and not as square box. Thansk Again

Comment: I don't think you can use `box-shadow` on your situation instead let's use `filter: drop-shadow`. I updated the code snippet above for you to check.